# Zabbix install issue

Tags: zabbix

I have a problem when installing zabbix as follows. Can someone please point me in the direction how to fix this

```
 dnf install zabbix-server-pgsql zabbix-web-pgsql zabbix-apache-conf zabbix-sql-scripts zabbix-agent
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                            891 kB/s |  10 MB     00:11
Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64                                                                                                                                                        19 kB/s |  29 kB     00:01
CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS                                                                                                                                                                   246 kB/s | 2.6 MB     00:10
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                    429 kB/s | 663 kB     00:01
Zabbix Official Repository non-supported - x86_64                                                                                                                                         993  B/s | 1.2 kB     00:01
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                                                316 kB/s | 7.5 MB     00:24
CentOS Linux 8 - Extras                                                                                                                                                                    18 kB/s | 9.6 kB     00:00
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package zabbix-server-pgsql-5.4.0-8.el8.x86_64 requires libodbc.so.2()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package zabbix-server-pgsql-5.4.1-1.el8.x86_64 requires libodbc.so.2()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package unixODBC-2.3.7-1.el8.x86_64 requires libreadline.so.7()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both readline-7.0-10.el8.x86_64 and readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64
  - package python-libs-2.7.5-90.el7.x86_64 requires libreadline.so.6()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - problem with installed package python-libs-2.7.5-90.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: `problem with installed package python-libs` update your system

Comment: Yes i have tried this doing a `dnf update`. But still i get the same issue. Any other idea

Comment: you are installing/using python2 on centos 8? you should only have python3 on centos 8

Comment: I had upgraded from Centos 7 to Centos 8 earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by reinstalling the Centos 8 from scratch